# What are the risks of visiting someone else's Google Photo while logged in?

Tags: account-security, google-apps

I was browsing Reddit on its official mobile app. I tapped on a photo to see a larger version. I was expecting to be lead to Imgur, but to my surprise it went to Google Photos.
Having the app for Google Photos, my phone (an Android device) opened that and showed the photo (an animated gif, iirc). I was logged in to Google Photos at that time, as that's coupled to the device account.

**What, if any are the security risks of having done this?**

I have no reason to believe anything malicious was intended or has ahppened, but is there anything I should do or check?

Answer (score 1):

Google will log your IP address and device type, then set or check some cookies to identify your device and see if you are signed in with a Google Account.

If you are concerned about being tracked by cookies, be sure to open strange links in private-browsing / incognito mode. To avoid having your actual IP address logged, consider using a proxy, VPN, or anonymizing browser such as Tor.

In your case, you may delete cookies and any cached files set during that session which may include the following:

> photos.google.com 
>   accounts.google.com 
>   content-people-pa.googleapis.com

Comment: I agree that that's good practice, however, when automatically opening an app from within another app, I have very little control _at that moment_ over how it's opened.